# Center a div (float: left;) in the mobile version

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a div with the float left property and I want to center this div in the mobile version.

I tried to put float none and clear both/left inside to the media query but nothing changed.

This is the code:

```css
.img-head {
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 980px) {
  .img-head {
    clear: both;
    text-align: center;
    float: none;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .img-head {
    clear: both;
    text-align: center;
    float: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="img-head">
  <img src="/nutickets2/images/evento-1.png">
</div>
```

Comment: .img-head img{margin:0;}

Comment: goes center in my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/7ojxbkmy/

Comment: @tech2017 auto margins don't work without a width.

Comment: I don't know why I had to use "!important" to force the CSS

Comment: @Matteo force what CSS? Do you have additional styles you're not including in your example? The styles you have shared will center the image within `.img-head` until the viewport is greater than `980px`, then it will float left. It currently center because you have `text-align: center;` applied and `<img>` is an inline element.

Comment: Yes, I have a lot of other codes and I think that there is conflict because also for other CSS I had to use !important. I have to check the code for this problem but I don't know where to start

Comment: keep the media query bellow of all css

Comment: Yes. its wokring correct.Maybe conflict with other class.

Comment: Ok, I put the media queries bellow all the css and now works well!

Answer (score 0):

By default. `<div>` display style is `block`. it will fit to 100% width of wrapper and height is auto.

To make this `<div>` position is center inside the wrapper **if** width of div is smaller than wrapper width you should set this `<div>`  to `display:inline-block;` (so width is not 100% automatically. With display:inline-block; this `<div>` will follow the width of content inside this `<div>` automatically). So after that, this `<div>` will have a gap (space with a wrapper). Now set margin left and right as `auto`. So position of this `<div>` will go to the center of wrapper.

```
.img-head {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    clear: both;
    text-align: center;
    float: none;
  }
```